# Get client IP in exim LXD container

Tags: proxy, exim, lxd

I set up an exim server in a Debian 10 container with LXD and then created a proxy device to map the SMTP port from the host to the container:

```
lxc config device add mycontainer myport25 proxy listen=tcp:x.x.x.x:25 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:25
```

where x.x.x.x is the host's public IP.

The port forwarding is working fine but, as I expected, the exim logs are showing the local IP instead of the remote servers ones. For example:

```
2020-10-07 13:45:40 1kQ7t6-0008P1-3M <= sender@remote.domain.com H=localhost (server.remote.domain.com) [127.0.0.1] P=esmtps X=TLS1.0:RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:256 CV=no S=14259 id=d0c331c0-2cb8-ac64-c75c-1cede50a6815@remote.domain.com
```

2020-10-07 13:45:40 1kQ7t6-0008P1-3M => |/usr/local/bin/script.php mailproxy@local.domain.com R=myrouter T=myrouter_pipe
2020-10-07 13:45:40 1kQ7t6-0008P1-3M Completed

Is it possible to get exim to show in the logs the forwarded IP instead of 127.0.0.1?

I read https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-proxies.html but if I use the hosts_proxy option, my server rejects incoming emails with this error: "503 Command refused, required Proxy negotiation failed".

I know I can forward the port using plain iptables in the host and the private IP of the container but I wonder if I can do it using the proxy feature of LXD.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I do apologize. I forgot to add the proxy_protocol=true to the command that creates the proxy:

```
lxc config device add mycontainer myport25 proxy listen=tcp:x.x.x.x:25 proxy_protocol=true connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:25
```

Now the exim logs show the sender server IP:

```
2020-10-07 16:45:21 1kQAgz-0000Hk-4g <= sender@remote.domaincom H=host.remote.domain.com [public_ip_here] P=esmtps X=TLS1.0:RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:256 CV=no S=14249 id=f4545bc8-763c-1553-fe62-be61439fe23f@remote.domain.com
```

2020-10-07 16:45:21 1kQAgz-0000Hk-4g => |/usr/local/bin/mailgate.php mailproxy@local.domain.com R=myrouter T=mytransport_pipe
2020-10-07 16:45:21 1kQAgz-0000Hk-4g Completed